# Caplet and Swaption Volatilities

Tags: volatility

Why is volatility always quoted in terms of caplet and swaption? Why not quoted in terms of other instruments?

Comment: these are the most liquid interest rate options.

Comment: you can also someties see quotes of bermudan european switch - the vol diff between the 2